# 2.8: when to be able to dissolve faces

Tags: edges

I'm not sure when I can dissolve faces or not.
For example I could dissolve the following two faces.

[image]

However, I couldn't do the ones. Nothing changed.

[image]

I don't understand why the difference occurs. So will anyone teach me the rules of dissolving faces? I attach the top and down views just in case.

top:
[image]

down:
[image]

Comment: It should work to dissolve those faces. There must be something wrong with your geometry. Check your model in wireframe mode for edges that cross but no vertex at the crossing, things like that. If you cant find anything then perhaps you could share your .blend file using this link to add it to your question   https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried that again and it worked.